# How to change a char within a String, that has been inputed by a scanner

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

so if the user enters "ABCD" how would i change a single char within this string?

example: user enters "ABCD". I want it to output 'T','B','G','D'. so that changed the A to T and C to G.

I tried using a the replace method but found that tedious (and didnt really work).
I want to try use a loop, checking each letter the user has entered and changing it to a different letter. Changing A to T, T to A and C to G, G to C.

```
public class test {

public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
userInput = input.nextLine();

char arrayInput[] = toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i > arrayInput.length; i++) {

switch(arrayInput[i]){

case 'a'
case 'A': change to 'T';
break;

case 't'
case 'T': change to 'A'

etc..

}}}}
```

something like that ^^. that could be totally wrong. but really need help! couldnt find any other help on the internet. thanks in advance

Comment: Why `replace` method didn't work?

Comment: cause i dont know how to use properly. maybe u can show me?

Answer (score 0):

Append the output to a `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder ouput=new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i > arrayInput.length; i++) {
 switch(arrayInput[i]){
  case 'a':
  case 'A': 
    output.append('T');
    break;
   // so on.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable so you have save the output of replace in another string

```
    String old ="ABCD";
    String newString = old.replace('A', 'T').replace('C', 'G');
    System.out.println(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop to traverse through the String like this-

`String s="ABCD";

    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)

    {
        if(s.charAt(i)=="A")
        s.charAt(i)="T";
     if(s.charAt(i)=="C")
        s.charAt(i)="G";
   }`

Use the charAt() to detect characters and replace them

Answer (score 0):

WOW! LOOKING BACK ON MY EARLY DAYS OF JAVA! Such an easy question now haha.